# OAuth with Google, no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on Redirect

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I follow the documentation but still getting this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at [short link](http://'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=152069873427-7fmg55847599d5ko1ejtb4khhpk4no.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle&scope=profile%20email&state=3643d736d1') (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/authenticate/google') from origin `null` has been blocked by CORS policy:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any idea how I can force the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the redirect header?

Comment: What is initiating the request that eventually gets redirected?

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown. Thanks for you early answer:

The Angular app is making a request to `http://localhost:8080/oauth/authenticate/google`. The spring-security-rest plugin is who return a redirection to the google' OAuth API, but the browser is rejecting it as it don't find the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (CORS).

Both apps (grails and angular) are running on my Laptop. back-end running on 8080 and front-end on the 4200